# How to call a method of a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I solved this issue by passing a unique date on each click.
But is there a good way to do it without a date?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  public set onClick(value: Date) {
    if (value) {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

And in parent template:

```
<child [onClick]="timestamp"></child>
<button (click)="timestamp= new Date"></button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a reference for child component `#child`. No need to create an input property just to invoke a method.

```
<child #child></child>
<button (click)="child.doSomething()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable in the view like this

```
<child #childComp></child>
<button (click)="childComp.onClick()"></button>
```

Edited

Comment: Wouldn't that be more like `<child #childComp></child>`
`<button (click)="childComp.someFunction()"></button>`